# Number of boxplots are inaccurate. How to fix it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my ggplot2 boxplot?

My dataframe looks like follows:

```
structure(list(month = structure(1:6, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
stat_year = c("2019/2020","2019/2020", "2019/2020", "2019/2020", "2019/2020","2019/2020"), 
treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Random","Animal"), class = "factor"), 
temp = c(3.22324156891496, 2.78498667711599, 5.22250073313783, 10.0049242424242, 3.9333986013986, 3.16336408243376)), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code I used to create the boxplot

```
sample.plot1 = ggplot(table1, aes(x = month, y = temp, group = treatment)) +
            geom_boxplot() + theme_classic()
sample.plot1 + facet_wrap(.~stat_year, ncol = 1)
```

Instead of showing two boxplots per each month, it shows two for the whole year.

[image]

What I need is for two treatments to show up for each month over the three winters.
I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: as far as I can see, the treatment group does not really serve you, because all entries are "Random" and none is "Animal".

Comment: The `group` aesthetic overrides any other aesthetics to determine which rows go into a single box. `group = treatment` means you want 1 box per treatment value, more-or-less ignoring the x-axis. Your sample data isn't very useful because it only contains "Random" treatment values, but I would think changing to `fill = treatment` instead of `group = treatment` would work - that will color each box by the treatment value and since you won't be overriding the x-axis grouping with `group` will do a set of boxes at each `month` value.

Comment: fill = treatment worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group aesthetic overrides any other aesthetics to determine which rows go into a single box. `group = treatment` means you want 1 box per treatment value, more-or-less ignoring the x-axis.

Your sample data isn't very useful because it only contains "Random" treatment values, but I would think changing to `fill = treatment` instead of `group = treatment` would work - that will color each box by the treatment value and since you won't be overriding the x-axis grouping with group will do a set of boxes at each month value.